# JDBC unable to connect to database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wrote some code to insert a table in a local database and I am getting the following error per the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:932)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:857)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:24)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: No timezone mapping entry for 'PDT'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:83)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2225)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1391)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:895)
    ... 7 more
```

Apparently, I could be wrong, but it has something to do with my timezone or the way the timezone is set in MySQL or the JDBC connector.

Here is my original source code:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection myConnection = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        //ResultSet rs = null;
        String sql = "create table student(student_id varchar(20) primary key, name varchar(30), class varchar(15), marks varchar(10);";

        try {
        /*
        Get Connection to jdbc
        */
        myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edureka?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "userOne", "password");

        /*Create an object for passing SQL queries to DB */
        myStmt = myConnection.createStatement();

        /*Execute a resulting statement to create a table in the DB */
        myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

        System.out.println("DB Table created in Database Edureka!");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the connection url by adding timezone info:

```
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/edureka?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=PDT", "userOne", "password");
```

Comment: It doesn't like PDT, most likely the actual location is needed.

Comment: Yah, sadly, that did not work.

Comment: @Al-geBra Following what @Peter said, try yo change to `serverTimezone=Europe/London`. Obviously, replace with your location. :)

Comment: @NiVeR and Peter Lawrey, when you say "it doesn't like PDT" are you referring to the JDBC?

Comment: Yes, you have no reason to dislike PDT, right? :D Try to apply that modification with the location.

Comment: It worked setting the serverTimezone to Europe/London :( they must really hate those of us here in Silicon Valley.